# Web API on IIS - Memory consumption is increased up until the app pool stack

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, memory-profiling

I have a Web API as a website on IIS. what happens is that some time the memory's app(inspecting by the file w3wp.exe in the task manager) start to increase until the app pool stack.

I read that it's may be issue of disposeable object that was not disposed. 
To analyse this issue, i was try to use the ".net memory profiler" from here: https://memprofiler.com

When i running the profiler, i get the result that shown in the attachment images.
[image: overview]
[image: undisposed instance]

Unfortunately i am not really understand the result, and how it's help me to prevent the memory increasing. and how it's help me to find the undisposes object.

Any help to understand the matter, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should focus on "live bytes" column, which indicates that a lot of strings (`System.String`) and bytes (`System.Byte[]`) are there. Check what are the strings and bytes, and from where they come from. Then try to modify your code if they are not necessary.

Comment: how can i know where to find in my code the problematic objects? the profiler supposed to direct me? because i can't find any clue. thanks!